# Unable to deploy war on tomcat from jenkins using Deploy to container Plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins, deployment

I am in learning face and trying to configure the jenkins and deploying war after successfully build to tomcat 7. However, I am able to create and build a job successfully. I am using **Deploy to container Plugin** to deploy my war file to the tomcat location but it is deploying in .m2 folder in c drive in user folder.

console output of job

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 56.433 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-10T22:13:16+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/49M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving E:\myProj\test\trunk\web\pom.xml to com.test/web/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving E:\myProj\test\trunk\web\target\web.war to com.er4u/web/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
channel stopped
Finished: SUCCESS
```

[tomcat configuration in job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnvsI.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my log:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 28.148s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 18 09:38:59 EST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/192M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/kft-activiti-demo/workspace/pom.xml to me.kafeitu.demo/kft-activiti-demo/v1/kft-activiti-demo-v1.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/kft-activiti-demo/workspace/target/kft-activiti-demo.war to me.kafeitu.demo/kft-activiti-demo/v1/kft-activiti-demo-v1.war
channel stopped
Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/kft-activiti-demo/workspace/target/kft-activiti-demo.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
  Redeploying [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/kft-activiti-demo/workspace/target/kft-activiti-demo.war]
  Undeploying [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/kft-activiti-demo/workspace/target/kft-activiti-demo.war]
  Deploying [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/kft-activiti-demo/workspace/target/kft-activiti-demo.war]
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: I am able to deploy my war using this plugin, but most of the time it failed to deploy the war if a war is already deployed on the sever. Can u help me out on this. :)